# query multiple tables that use the same fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using bigquery to query two datasets that share a schema:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
  SELECT
    name as name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(details, r"(value=\w+)") as regex
  FROM
    Dataset.table1,
    Dataset.table2 )
WHERE
  ARRAY_LENGTH(regex) > 0
```

But I get the error that the "name" field is ambiguous, which makes sense since I am not specifying either of the two tables.

Is there a way to query shared fields from 2+ tables at once like this?

Comment: Maybe add sample data and expected results?  You are currently creating a cartesian product between the 2 tables.  You should probably be using a `join` or `union`, but it's difficult to know without sample data.

Comment: You can resolve this by including aliases which determine from which table you select the `name` column.

Answer (score 2):

Because of use of ARRAY_LENGTH and REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL it looks like you are using `BigQuery Standard SQL` mode.
At the same time you are still using Legacy SQL notion of `UNION ALL` via use of `comma` - which is not a case for Standard SQL!
You should use explicit UNION ALL
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tablename.columnname 
Use the below query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
  SELECT
    table1.name as name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(details, r"(value=\w+)") as regex
  FROM
    Dataset.table1,
    Dataset.table2 )
WHERE
  ARRAY_LENGTH(regex) > 0
```

Comment: Doesn't this only pull results from table1 then? That's the result that I'm seeing when I try this